# Can't open video files

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I could open video files but then I installed ffmpeg to install opencv and now it does not open video files. I tried vlc and ubuntu's Movie Player to open .mkv, .avi, and .mp4 but none of them opened. When I try opening them from the command line with vlc I get this:

> [0x2145070] mkv demux error: cannot load some cues/chapters/tags etc. (broken seekhead or file)
>   [0x2145070] mkv demux error: cannot load some cues/chapters/tags etc. (broken seekhead or file)
>   Segmentation fault

I have ubuntu 11.10 64bit. 
I used [this](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) guide to install ffmpeg. When configuring x264 and ffmpeg I enabled shared and fPIC.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This might be memory related.  Try to do a memory check.

Comment: Happy you've solved the problem. Mind explaining a bit how you eventually solved the problem? I have a few different solutions in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very odd. VLC has the codecs built-in, so it should not matter what you do with ffmpeg. Unless installing ffmpeg somehow messed up a library VLC was depending on...

The error you get sounds to me like there is something wrong with the file you're trying to open. Bit too basic maybe, but have you tried opening another video file, including one with a different file type (e.g. avi)?